# Update Record Type assignment per profile via API

Tags: api

I have a tool that automatically assigns access to Custom Metadata objects, Apex Classes and adds Object permissions and Field permissions.

I now have a requirement to add `Record Type` access to `Profile` (or the underlying permission set).

When I am adding Custom Metadata or Apex Class I use `SetupEntityAccess` in normal REST Api.
When I am adding `ObjectPermissions` or `FieldPermissions` I just create them as objects via Tooling API.

What Salesforce object describes Record Type access to Profile?